# Conditional Formatting for three columns range and their sum

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

My Input:

```
A   B   C
5   2   3
5   2   4
```

I want to conditionally format the row such as `if A is not equal to B+C`, then the entire row should be highlighted in red. In my case, second row should be highlighted as `5 != 2 + 4`.

What I tried is adding a custom formula to `the range - A2:C` and the formula I tried is:

`=A3 <> SUM(B3, C3)` and some other ways, but couldn't figure it out.

PS: I want to create this formatting check for the entire column not just for a single row.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: try this formula `=$A2<>SUM($B2:$C2)` for range A2:C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Sergey's comment. The working formula is `=$A2<>SUM($B2:$C2)` for the `range A2:C`.